# SQL: Generate a string dynamically with condition using a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate a string in SQL Server with a contingent using a Stored Procedure.
Lets say I have a table as

```
ID   FileKey
1    AEDAT
2    ERDAT
```

Now I want to generate a string as follows:

```
AEDAT GT LastUpdatedValue OR ERDAT GT LastUpdatedValue
```

Now if the above table contains only one row (With `FileKey`) AEDAT then the resultant string should be

```
AEDAT GT LastUpdatedValue  <---No OR operator
```

And if there are, say, 3 or 4 rows in the above table then the resultant string would be like :

```
AEDAT GT LastUpdatedValue OR ERDAT GT LastUpdatedValue OR MCVBL GT LastUpdatedValue...
```

Now to achieve the same I am taking the following approach:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50)
SELECT @ColumnName = STRING_AGG(x.ColumnName + 'GT LastUpdatedValue',' OR ') FROM <table_name> x;
```

With the above I have two questions:

1. The above is not working i.e. I am not getting `@ColumnName` values as `AEDAT,ERDAT`. What I am missing? --- This one is resolved.
2. Assume that I get `@ColumnName` as `AEDAT,ERDAT`. How can I generate the dynamic and contingent string as given above? --- This is also now resolved.

Comment: This *looks* like you just want string aggregation, where `' OR '` is the delimiter, and you suffix all your values with `' GT LastUpdatedValue'`. I suggest looking at `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Sever 2018.

Comment: @Larnu: What about the 1st question?

Comment: *"SQL Sever 2018"* That doesn't exist, @pythondumb . The latest release of SQL Server is 2019, and the one prior to that was 2017; there was no release in 2018.

Comment: I'd, personally, bin the `WHILE` first, @pythondumb; SQL is a set based language and a `WHILE` is the complete opposite to that. Use a set based solution (i.e. `STRING_AGG`).

Comment: @pythondumb Did you mean 2019 or 2008? if the first, than use `string_agg`. If the second, consider upgrading your sql server as it's extended support period has ended a long time ago.

Comment: My bad...It is SQL Server 2019.

Comment: I have edited the question with `STRING_AGG` in place. But I need some clue on generating that dynamic string (question 2). I have further edited the question with using ' OR ' as separator and adding ' GT ' as hardcoded.

Comment: So would `x.ColumnName + ' GT ' + @ColumnName` not work? I don't follow the problem here

Comment: Where is `LastUpdatedValue` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the following

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50) = (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(CAST(x.ColumnName + ' GT LastUpdatedValue' AS varchar(max)), ' OR ')
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x.ID)
    FROM <table_name> x
);
```

You need to cast to `(max)` otherwise it gets cut off at 8000 characters (or 4000 for `nvarchar`)

Answer (score 0):

```
   declare @t table(ID int,   FileKey varchar(20))
    insert into @t values
    (1,   'AEDAT'),
    (2 ,   'ERDAT')
    
    
    SELECT TOP 1
(
    SELECT FileKey + ' GT LastUpdatedValue' + CASE
                                                  WHEN id < 2
                                                  THEN ' OR '
                                                  ELSE ''
                                              END
    FROM @t t1 FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM @t t;
```

if you share exact table and requirement then logic like  `WHEN id < 2` can be handle in some other dynamic and efficient way. Removing last `OR` with string manipulation may be lengthy.

Comment: `FOR XML PATH(''))` should be `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` to prevent XML escaping, also you need an `ORDER BY` otherwise your `OR` will be wrong